# How can I install a local Python package into an Anaconda environment?

Tags: pip, anaconda, python-wheel

How can I install a local Python package (`.whl`) into an Anaconda environment?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem the following way:

If you have a non-conda pip as your default pip but conda python is your default python (as below)

```
>which -a pip
/home/<user>/.local/bin/pip   
/home/<user>/.conda/envs/newenv/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip

>which -a python
/home/<user>/.conda/envs/newenv/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Then instead of just calling pip install , you can use the module flag -m with python so that it uses the anaconda python for the installation

python -m pip install

This installs the package to the anaconda library directory rather than to the library directory associated with (the non-anaconda) pip

Comment: Do you know the approach for Windows OS as well ;)

Comment: @thinwybk Same solution applies. Only have to use `where` instead of `which`

Comment: Thx for this windows noob hint ;)